# Why doesn't google.com use CSP?

Tags: security, content-security-policy

When checking Google's HTTP headers I noticed there is no CSP header. Considering they led great efforts when dealing with CSP level 3, I wonder why is that so?

[HTTP headers](https://observatory.mozilla.org/analyze/google.com)

Comment: While their might now use it on google.com they are using it a lot of places - e.g. meet.google.com. See https://www.eweek.com/security/how-google-is-using-content-security-policy-to-mitigate-web-flaws/ - they reference this great talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBBqtrJmMRc&index=12&list=PLpr-xdpM8wG8RHOguwOZhUHkKiDeWpvFp

Comment: Thank you for the links, but this still does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I realized google.com does use CSP indeed. [CSP can be used directly from a `meta` tag](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp#the_meta_tag) instead of a HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

Actually now Aug-2022, I see the following reponse header.

```
content-security-policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-CBtB0pB_6ERNGUP11XPOxw' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/cdt1
```